# failed to parse xml file eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to make a basic menu with one button.

I get this error every time I go to look at the Graphical Layout of the xml file:

```
activity_main.xml: Failed to parse file 
C:\Users\...\eclipse\workspace\Library\res\menu\activity_main.xml

org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag menu
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:877)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:208)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:782)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3336)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3273)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:421)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:184)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:86)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:131)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:321)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:331)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1638)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1389)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1163)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:674)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:360)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:292)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3023)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1730)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:270)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

This is my code in the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@menu/activity_main"
tools:context="com.jbalaka.library.Library" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/library" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The other error it gives me is

> layoutlib.jar is missing!

Comment: your posted xml is missing `</RelativeLayout>` at the end. Also, your xml does not have an xml declaration.

Comment: I added both things and it still gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Clean project & clear Lint.

Lint warnings produce weird errors/warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with creating a new project in the same workspace and compared the files to see if there was any differences that could be the error and I found out that I'd written `android:background=` something in the `<RelativeLayout` in the activity_main.xml file and that it didn't link to any background or any color and then I removed that code row the graphical layout did load correctly again and I could remove the project I compared with, so I recommend you to remove the `android:background="@menu/activity_main"` part of your code and see if it helps.